# How to connect to a different device on the same network with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, client, hosting

Just wondering if there is something between localhost and web hosting. What my question is is that is it possible to easily get client-side JavaScript to communicate with a Node server on the same network without having to host the website?

Some pseudo-code:

```
    let express = require("express");
    let app = express();
    app.listen(/*some way of external connection on the same network instead of port*/, () => {
      console.log("I got a request froom an external device.");
    });
```

Any help would be appreciated! :)

Comment: It is not clear what you want.

Comment: Does this make more sense?

Comment: Just use your LAN Ip... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_area_network

Comment: Thanks for the help! Could I have a code example of how to do this? I have thought of this but I didn't know how to script it.

Comment: Find out what LAN IP the machine has where you want to host the code, put "0.0.0.0" as adress argument for `.listen` and with a other device open a browser and put `http://<lan ip>:<port>` in the adress bar. It couldn't be easier.

Comment: Ok thanks, will try it out. :)

Comment: One last thing, what is the address argument. Sorry, my field of expertise is Java not JavaScript. :)